# atomicity in galera multi-master

Tags: mysql, mariadb, galera, acid

Maybe this question is so obvious it doesn't bear asking, but I haven't been able to answer it from the internet.

In the case of Galera multi-master replication, is this statement still guaranteed to be atomic?

```sql
UPDATE table 
SET col = new_value 
WHERE
  primary_key = ? and col = old_value;
```

in that if two clients issued the same request for a given `primary_key` and `old_value`, only one would successfully update a row, is that correct?

Comment: If one of them has `new_value` = `old_value`, then both could succeed.

Comment: And both succeeding would still be atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Atomicity is correct even if both clients are updating on different cluster members.

Upon commit, (even if explicit), like locally, one of the client's will get a DEADLOCK error.

Reference: [certification based replication](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/certification-based-replication.html)